# How to update servlet asynchronously upon reading data from AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, iot

I am working on a IoT project where AWS IoT service is used to store a record in a DynamoDB table whenever data is retrieved from sensor (connected to RPI) .

I am able to connect to DynamoDB from my Java code and fetch the data, as expected, but I'm trying to go further and accomplish the following:

- How can I get *data in real time* ?
- How can I show sensor data in a web app, as a chart that gets *updated once-per-second whenever the sensor has available data*. In other words, when a new record is added in DynamoDB, I want it to be shown in my Servlet.

Is there anyway to make this communication asynchronous (sockets for instance)?

I have searched on DynamoDB streams but I don't see how to open communication with AWS from my program.

Comment: How is the data getting into DynamoDB?

Comment: I have created a rule which will be executed every time sensor data is published in AWS IoT.

Comment: Enable a stream on the table and have your servlet (using the AWS Java SDK) connect to a streams endpoint so that your servlet can read and process updates/inserts in the stream. Independently, have your clients long-poll the servlet (or listen via websockets?) for updates.

Comment: Hi @jarmod , thank you I will try to implement this solution, what I want to achieve via websockets is like an Mqtt pub/sub thing, where data is updated in real time. Since I will open a socket endpoint in my servlet do I need to open another endpoint on DynamoDB ?Thank you.